# Why is $H \rtimes_{\varphi} K$ isomorphic to $H \rtimes_{\varphi \circ \phi} K$ where $\phi \in \text{Aut}(K)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, semidirect-product

Why is $H \rtimes_{\varphi} K$ isomorphic to $H \rtimes_{\varphi \circ \phi} K$ where $\phi \in \text{Aut}(K)$?

I can see that $\varphi(K) = \varphi(\phi(K))$, but it is not clear to me how the semidirect products themselves are isomorphic. I tried constructing an isomorphism, but they were really messy and didn't seem to go anywhere.

Is there any easy way to see why this is true?

Comment: I still don't know much about semidirect products, but found Jyrki's answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2194198/120540) helpful in general. Maybe you're already aware of these things about homomorphisms out of semidirect products, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to use the usual notation, and write your groups as $H \rtimes_{\varphi} K$ (the normal subgroup  doesn't get the extra bar on the product sign).

Let's write the general element of $H \rtimes_{\varphi} K$ as $kh$, where the product is given by
$$ (k_1h_1)(k_2h_2) = (k_1k_2)(h_1^{\varphi(k_2)}h_2) $$

You can then define a map $f:H \rtimes_{\varphi} K\rightarrow H \rtimes_{\varphi \circ \phi} K$ 
$$ f(kh) = \phi^{-1}(k)h$$

This is clearly a bijection as a set map, so it just remains to show it's a homomorphism.  We have
\begin{align}
f(k_1h_1k_2h_2) &= f(k_1k_2h_1^{\varphi(k_2)}h_2)\\
&= \phi^{-1}(k_1k_2)h_1^{\varphi(k_2)}h_2\\
&= \phi^{-1}(k_1)\phi^{-1}(k_2)h_1^{\varphi(k_2)}h_2
\end{align}

Meanwhile, in $H \rtimes_{\varphi \circ \phi} K$,
\begin{align}
f(k_1h_1)f(k_2h_2) &= \phi^{-1}(k)h_1\phi^{-1}(k)h_2\\
&= \phi^{-1}(k_1)\phi^{-1}(k_2)h_1^{\varphi \circ \phi\circ \phi^{-1}(k_2)}h_2\\
&= \phi^{-1}(k_1)\phi^{-1}(k_2)h_1^{\varphi(k_2)}h_2
\end{align}

which agrees with the above. So this is an isomorphism.

Comment: That’s perfect, thanks! Also, thanks for pointing out the notation typo, fixed it.